# ios - What is the best way to get a list of states in a country?

Tags: ios, location

I'm looking for a good solution for getting a list of states in a country.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's good idea to check these questions:

[How to get the state,country list in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14892998/how-to-get-the-state-country-list-in-ios)

[iOS - is a user in the United States?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12205539/ios-is-a-user-in-the-united-states)

this one ins't for iOS but can be useful too:

[Where can I get a list of Countries, States and Cities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627654/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-countries-states-and-cities)

Answer (score 1):

I dnt think there is an easy way to retrieve this.. you need to target set of countries that your product will cater and build up the states list for those countries (google should be able to help you with that) and for others make the state field an user input field.

I am not sure if anybody would be interested in sharing data that they already have with them.