# Dim_geography csv?

Tags: data-warehouse, dimension, geography

EDIT *
Is there somewhere a csv file with Geographical infomation on like a dim_geography. I mean i could go create it, but im thinking there must be a csv file or something similar out there that will provide me with the hierarchies I need to create the table in our DWH

My basic need.....

List of all these in the world

```
Level     Name
 1        Continent
 2        Country
 3        State/Provence
 4        City
```

Comment: I think you need to create this dimension on your own, since the contents of it will depend on your use case (could departments, roads, countries, branches, etc.) and your need of resolution.

Comment: I agree. However my need is very basic and I do believe there will be something that will get me 80% there out there.

Comment: Still depends what your "basic" need is. You should [edit] your question and be more specific.

Comment: See very basic... hence i said basic without explanation

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627654/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-countries-states-and-cities I think the accepted answer in this thread answers your needs